# How does fgetc() know the next character's address? How to retrieve the current character address?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");

    while(feof(fp))
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c",ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How does `fgetc()` know which character to <s>print</s> read (because `fp` remains same throughout the program, not incremented); same for how does it identify `EOF`? I mean, what does it actually refer to get to know where exactly it is now?
How can I retrieve that memory address and print it?

Comment: `fgetc` does not print anything. What do you mean?? Your use of `feof` is plain wrong and `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` intentionally. Never use it with `char`!

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for why your loop is wrong.

Comment: Also remember that `fgetc()` and its friends return an `int`, not just a `char`.

Answer (score 6):

A `FILE *` is not actually a pointer into a file which you can increment and decrement to read from; instead, it is a pointer to a `struct FILE` object. Different libraries have different definitions for the struct, but essentially, there are fields within the struct that will internally track the current location into the file.

Here is an example implementation of `fgetc` (reproduced from [here](http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/3.x/src/lib/libc/fgetc.c)):

```
int
fgetc(FILE *fp)
{
    int cnt;
    unsigned char c;

    if (fp->ungetcflag) {
        fp->ungetcflag = 0;
        return fp->ungetchar;
    }
    cnt = read(fp->fd, &c, 1);
    if (cnt <= 0)
        return EOF;
    return c;
}
```

`fgetc` just internally calls `read` to fetch the next character. You can continue down the rabbit hole and eventually find out where the `struct FILE`'s internal state is changed to reflect having fetched a new character.

For more detail specific to your version of `fgetc`, you'll have to look at the source of your machine's C library.

Answer (score 3):

`FILE` *is* [very likely] a data structure containing information regarding the opened (with `fopen()`) file. One of the structure members is the current file position (or offset) [implementation defined, but let's assume that this is the case].

Everytime you read or write to the file pointed by `fp`, this structure member is incremented. `fseek()` may be used to set the file position. `ftell()` will return the current file position, which, in this case, is what you're looking for.

The value of `fp` [a memory address] is unchanged, because, as I said, it is a *pointer* to a data structure [again, implementation defined, but this is probably true for every implementation] that was allocated when `fopen()` was invoked, and will be released when `fclose()` is called. What changes is the structure member values.

Comment: Not [may be], but [very likely], in my opinion.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agree. Maybe I'm being too conservative here. I'll take your tip and update the answer.